# Since what Android version do I need to activate GPS to know WiFi SSID?

Tags: android

I'm developing and App that must connect to an specific SSID but some new phones needs to have the GPS active in order to let the App read the WiFI SSID.

API 27 maybe?

Comment: See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan#wifi-scan-permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android 8 - api level 26 - (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan)